# Spring-MVC: JSP <form action> view sends series of values to the controller instead of one value of the button clicked

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

```
<form name="update" id="update" action="update" method="post">
<table border="0">
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Del</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Remarks</th>
</tr>

<c:forEach items="${recList}" var="rec" varStatus="loop">
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="del" value="${loop.index}"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" value="${rec.getName()}"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="address" value="${rec.getAddress()}"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="remarks" value="${rec.getRemarks()}"/></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="index" value="${loop.index}"/>
<input type="submit" value="Update"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>

</table>
</form>
```

This is my code for this view

[image]

My problem is when I click the UPDATE button, the form seems to send series of values like

```
name= "aiko,hashimoto,yuki,ode"
```

instead of sending only

```
name="hashimoto"
```

to the Controller if second UPDATE button is clicked. Can anyone help me with my issue?
`<form>` tag can't be inside `<table>`. By logic, I think it's best to put the  inside the loop but it is not possible. Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: The problem is that *all** of your `update` buttons are calling a form `POST` - I suggest that you change your code so that `updat` has an `id` and that the `click` will call Javascript (jquery) and then you call some ajax code - I guess that you can delete your other question

Comment: @ScaryWombat but i am using spring-mvc. I think I don't need to use JS or AJAX for this, if i am not mistaken

Comment: Why do you think this? Where is that written?  How should the HTML guess which `update` button has been clicked?

Comment: The button will post a form, your form is enclosing everything. `either make a form per row, or use a javascript submit solutions to submit only the row you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Submit your form with javascript function using ajax call like below sample code.
    send single value from form submit not possible 

    function submitform(){

         var messageId = $("#messageId").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'<c:url value="/dummy/dummyMessageId"/>',
            datatype:'JSON',    
            data: 'messageId=' + messageId ,
            success : function(response) {
            if (null != response && response.success) {      
              } else {
                    var errorDiv = $('#Error');
                    errorDiv.html(response.error.message);
                    }
                }               
        });
    }
    <input type="button" value="Update" onclick="submitform()"/></td> 
   add above code  in your HTML input button
```